# Complexity of optimizing a bi-objective function with integer constraints

Tags: algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization

I have two different objective functions, each of which can be solved optimally in polynomial time. Does this mean, I can optimize a linear combination of these objective functions in polynomial time too? Note that the objective functions are not convex, since they have integer variables.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the two functions range over disjoint domains, you probably can do binary search as needed.  If the functions share a domain, you have interactions which may take more than polynomial time to resolve.  It may be possible to divide the domain into finitely many regions and solve the problem quickly in each region, but it is not clear that you will have only polynomially many such regions.  Gerhard "Hopefully They Are Convex Enough" Paseman, 2015.03.17

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks a lot. Could you please provide any reference where I can get a deeper understanding of this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the literature.  The right hand side bar has a list of related questions on MathOverflow.  A random walk using the Related list as a step may after a short time give you a good pointer. Gerhard "No Polynomial Time Bound Guarantee" Paseman, 2015.03.17